# How can I format date labels in a CRM 2011 chart

Tags: xml, charts, dynamics-crm-2011, customization

I have a stacked chart in CRM 2011 which is ordered by year. In order to retrieve data for the 3 latest years, the year is stored in a date field.

However, the x-axis labels in the graph are displayed as

- "Jan 2011" (2011-01-01)
- "Jan 2012" (2012-01-01)
- and so on.

I would really like to strip everything but the year-part. Is it possible?

I have tried to change the label formatting with no luck:

```
<AxisX><LabelStyle Format="yyyy" /></AxisX>
```

Comment: can you include all the xml? I think it's necessary to change the dategrouping property inside the fetchcollection

Comment: You are so spot on! See my answer.

Comment: isn't necessary, you found the solution by yourself :)

Answer (score 3):

While I never found the solution searching the internet, I suddenly spotted an attribute in the fetch-part of the xml:

```
  <fetchcollection>
    <fetch mapping="logical" aggregate="true">
      <entity name="ci_customersurveyanswer">
        <attribute groupby="true" alias="_year" dategrouping="month" name="ci_year" />
      </entity>
    </fetch>
  </fetchcollection>
```

Where the `dategrouping` is the key. Changing it to `dategrouping="year"` did the trick.